# React native setState inside onChange function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I have _onChange function on ModalSelector and I need to get few things from my Firebase database.

1) If I use this inside GetTeamOption(option)

```
this.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}
```

It doesn't work. When I log that state it seems like it's empty string.

2) If I use this inside GetTeamOption(option)

```
self.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}, () => {});
```

Log isn't empty already but it logs same value, first one. Actually I have that problem only in onChange function. I use almost same code in componentDidMount function for another data and 1) example works as I want.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Loaded: false,
        Optionn:'',
        LeagueOption: '',
        TeamOption: '',
        LeagueRequest: '',
        TeamRequest: '',
        TeamsToMapRequest: [],
        LeaguesToMapRequest: []
    }
}

  GetTeamOption(option){
        const self = this;
        let index = 0;
        let object = {};
        let TeamsArr = [];
    this.setState({LeagueOption: option.label}, function () {
        const refTeam = firebase.database().ref('leagues/' + this.state.LeagueOption + '/');
        refTeam.orderByChild('Team').on("value", function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
                const childComplete = child.val().Team;
                console.log(childComplete); 
               //There I get 2 teams
               //FirstTeam
               //SecondTeam

               //First case
                self.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}, () => {
                    console.log(self.state.TeamRequest);
                    //There I get this
                    //FirstTeam
                    //FirstTeam
                });

                //Second case
                this.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}
                    console.log(self.state.TeamRequest);
                    //Log here is empty

            });
        });
    });
}
```

return() function

```
<ModalSelector onChange={ (option) => { this.GetTeamOption(option) } data={this.state.LeaguesToMapRequest}>
      <TextInput value={this.state.LeagueOption} />
</ModalSelector>
```

Comment: You are declaring the function incorrectly, so it is out of scope. Lets assume you're using ES6, do it like this: GetTeamOption = (option) => {...}

Comment: @fungusanthrax, It is not out of scope, `this` context is lost. It needs to be bound to `this` for it to work. EDIT: Unless of course it was bound in the constructor.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst It was bound in the constructor. I edited code.

Comment: @DavidFutera, no it is not bound. You function `GetTeamOption` has no reference of `this`. You can fix that by using the [class properties](https://michalzalecki.com/react-components-and-class-properties/) mentioned by @fungunsanthrax

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Well I tried few different ways as soon as I read that article. Unfortunately I didn't get result which I wanted :(. I think I finally understood bind, but it is not working here. Maybe it is not problem with bind or I just understood it badly. fungunsanthrax's - advice didn't help too. Could you post my code edited? I would like to check if I was wrong or it's not problem with bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Loaded: false,
        Optionn:'',
        LeagueOption: '',
        TeamOption: '',
        LeagueRequest: '',
        TeamRequest: '',
        TeamsToMapRequest: [],
        LeaguesToMapRequest: []
    }
}


GetTeamOption = (option) => {
    let index = 0;
    let object = {};
    let TeamsArr = [];
    this.setState({LeagueOption: option.label}, () => {
      const refTeam = firebase.database().ref('leagues/' + this.state.LeagueOption + '/');
      refTeam.orderByChild('Team').on("value", (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          const childComplete = child.val().Team;
          console.log(childComplete);
          //There I get 2 teams
          //FirstTeam
          //SecondTeam

          //First case
          this.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.TeamRequest);
            //There I get this
            //FirstTeam
            //FirstTeam
          });

          //Second case
          this.setState({TeamRequest: childComplete}
          console.log(this.state.TeamRequest);
          //Log here is empty

        });
      });
    });
}
```

It looks like your problem is using `function` statements instead of arrow functions. Arrow functions do not have their own scope, they inherit their scope. Using the function keyword will give your function its own scope. I removed references to self.

You can also use either `this.GameTeamOption = this.GameTeamOption.bind(this);` in your constructor to bind your component's `this` context to your function, or you can declare it as an arrow function (that's the method I took).

Comment: Didn't help too. I used simple const and it works finally. Otherwise I still have no idea why state doesn't work.